# Subtract all items in a list against each other

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations

I have a list in Python that looks like this:

```
myList = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,5)]
```

And I want to subtract each item with the others, like this:

```
(1,1) - (2,2)
(1,1) - (3,3)
(1,1) - (4,5)
(2,2) - (3,3)
(2,2) - (4,5)
(3,3) - (4,5)
```

The expected result would be a list with the answers:

```
[(1,1), (2,2), (3,4), (1,1), (2,3), (1,2)]
```

How can I do this? If I approach it with a `for` loop, I can maybe store the previous item and check it against the one that I'm working with at that moment, but it doesn't really work.

Comment: what is `(1 , 1) - (2 , 2)`? `(-1, -1)` or something else?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, yes, (-1,-1) or (1,1). Either, I don't care about the sign.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` with tuple unpacking to generate the pairs of differences:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [(y1-x1, y2-x2) for (x1, x2), (y1, y2) in combinations(myList, 2)]                    
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a list comprehension, with `np.subtract` to 'subtract' the tuples from each other:

```
import numpy as np

myList = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,5)]

answer = [tuple(np.subtract(y, x)) for x in myList for y in myList[myList.index(x)+1:]]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.sub) with [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> import operator
>>> myList = [(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(4, 5)]
>>> [(operator.sub(*x), operator.sub(*y)) for x, y in (zip(ys, xs) for xs, ys in combinations(myList, 2))]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (1, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
>>>
```